# Find Core temp with sensors command

Tags: sensors

I am trying to get a returned value with the 2 digits temp with `sensors` command, which shows me this:

```
$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:      +40.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)  
Core 8:      +35.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)  
Core 9:      +40.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)  
Core 10:     +38.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)  

coretemp-isa-0001
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:      +38.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)  
Core 1:      +37.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)  
Core 9:      +30.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)  
Core 10:     +31.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)
```

With the following command I have been able to get returned the values, but I need to get values one by one:

```
sensors | awk '{if (match($0, "Core 0")){printf("%d",$3);} }'
```

Returns: 4038

Is there a way to get first or sencond occurrence one by one?

Comment: accurate data samples and expected results please

Comment: Hi Mug, if I run this same comand on a single processor machine I get a return of the actual Core temp, for example on server 1 I run the same command (sensors | awk '{if (match($0, "Core 0")){printf("%d",$3);} }') and get a 2 digits number back, like 31, but on the 2 processors server as there are 2 Core 0 I get both numers back like 3131

Answer (score 3):

Looking at `man sensors`

You could use: `sensors -j`

This returns the data formatted in JSON which then could be parsed and trimmed for the values you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sensors | sed -rn 's/.*Core 0:\s+([^ ]+).*/\1/p'
+40.0°C
+38.0°C

$ sensors | sed -rn 's/.*Core 0:\s+.([0-9.]+).*/\1/p'
40.0
38.0

$ sensors | sed -rn 's/.*Core 0:\s+.([0-9]+).*/\1/p'
40
38
```

Comment: Hi Mug, thanks a lot for your quick reply!, I have tryed this solution but non of them is returning a output (at least on screen), my system is a Centos 6, not sure if that helps or is relevant.

Comment: what version your grep is ?

Comment: I have updated the answer using sed

Comment: grep (GNU grep) 2.20, I'll try with sed and let you know if that worked

Comment: I think your sample data is not the same as real one. i have tested with data in your question

Comment: use code sample button "{ }" when embed data in your question